# TFS: Condition for transition on field-based rule

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

How to create a rule to skip transitions or choose other ones by specific field volume?

I've created a custom workflow for Item and there are a lot of States \ Fields inside. Some States have to be skipped by Fields volumes but i can't create another Item because of general restriction.

Comment: Not fully understanding your question... Can you add more details? Plus, much of this isn't possible in the new 2019/Azure DevOps  type process template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not change a state based on filed rules. You could also not able to skip transitions by specific field volume.

For System fields, there is some restriction for them. Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=tfs-2018#system-field-rules) for details:

> System fields have System.Name reference names, for example
>   System.Title and **System.State**. TFS restricts customization of
>   these fields, except for these instances:

Transitions define the valid progressions and regressions between states. **Users can specify only those states that are valid based on the transitions** that you define for the current state.

In the other word, Transitions tell the TFS which state can be followed by the current one.

A transition always has a from and to state. You could not **ignore** or skip the transition and select a totally different state. It's not available at present.

For more details of this related concept, you could take a look at our official tutorial here-- [Workflow design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/change-workflow-wit?view=azure-devops#workflow-design-guidelines)

Comment: Can I propose a choice for next transitions based on field volume?
Example: Item is at State_1 and next ones could be State_2 or State_3. If Field=Volume_2 -> next ones could be only State_2; If Field=Volume_3 -> State could be only State_3. Possible?

Comment: Or another workaround: check on State_2 (State_3) the volume in the Field and make the transition impossible. Any option with WHEN* condition?

Comment: @a.tolik  Unfortunately, it's also not able to this. For [When condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=azure-devops-2019#require-read-only-and-restrict-values) Specifies the rules to apply to the parent field when another field is assigned a specified value. But it also not able to bypass the restriction of System fields. You could do the opposite thing, based on stated change to change a filed value. But could not  change a state based on filed value changed at present. Sorry for the inconvenience.